# SQLite Custom ORDER BY over Strings causing Parser Stack Overflow

Tags: sqlite, sorting, sql-order-by

I wrote a custom SQLite 'sort' over strings that basically replaces each relevant substring by an alphabetic letter in the appropriate place in the alphabet.

The problem is pretty simple - there are too many REPLACE statements running around causing a parser stack overflow.

For example, the statement looks something like: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(...REPLACE('alpha','A'), 'beta','B'), 'gamma','C')...);`

The total count of REPLACE calls is 66.

My current work-around is just to use a custom function to apply the replacements (since I am using the sqlite c api), but it would be nice to be able to do this in SQLite itself, rather than having to use a c callback.

Is it possible? Is there a better solution?

Comment: It might be possible to write a recursive CTE to iterate over all replacements, but that would be horribly inefficient.

Comment: What you're doing now is the best approach; sql in general sucks for string manipulation.